# how to get Binding of textBox in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

I want to getBinding of a control's property in wpf (like setBinding(Dp,Binding)). After that I want to add more binding to that one, like add validationRule in code (not in xaml). Can anyone reply with sample code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
BindingExpression bindingExpression = c_textBox1.GetBindingExpression(TextBox.TextProperty);
    Binding parentBinding = bindingExpression.ParentBinding;

    //make new MultiBinding expression and add parentBinding into it.
     MultiBinding bindingList = new MultiBInding();
     bindingList.Bindings.Add(parentBinding);
    c_textBox1.SetBinding(TextBox.TextProperty, bindingList);
```

Comment: Thanks Brother i got your point and i implement your code in TextBox initialized method. Is there any other suitable place where i keep my implementation. At textBox initialized method i am facing issue, Xmal Desiger raise exeption, but at runtime its ok